# grails criteria query return empty result

Tags: oracle, hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I have a domain structure, as given below

```
class Parent {
  static hasMany = [childs:Child]
}

class Child {
 int gender
 string height
}
```

Now, i want to get list of all parents, who have a boy(gender=1) with less than '180' cm height **AND** a girl(gender=2) with more than '150' cm height.

I tried a criteria as given below

```
def criteria = Parent.createCriteria()
def parents = criteria.list() {
        childs {
            and {
                and {
                    eq("gender", 2)
                    ge("height", 150)
                }
                and {
                    eq("gender", 1)
                    le("height", 180)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but it returns a empty list although there are valid data.

Comment: If `height` is a `String` property of your domain you can't use `ge` or `le` to compare it as a numeric. That's going to do a `String` comparison.

Comment: @JoshuaMoore but srting comparison works fine.. ie: if i go for boy case it works fine but quering both girl and boy gives empty result.

Comment: That's because your query is trying to match Parent records which have a single child record that has gender 2 AND gender 1. Which will never be the case. You need to run two queries, one to find the boys and one to find the girls then get a unique list between the two. This kind of question has been asked multiple times here on stackoverflow.

Comment: @JoshuaMoore ok,it is one of the solution but  i Also needed to retrive count of parents with this condition before retriving whole  data, Since data can be in thousands. how it practically possible to find count?

Comment: @AnIshA, is it possible for to post generating query?

Answer (score 1):

Change the `'and'` to `'or'` after 'childs'. Because, the logical `'or'` tries to find the **union** between the two queries which would always be null.

```
List<Parent> parents = Parent.createCriteria().listDistinct {
      and {
          childs {
              or {
                  and {
                      eq("gender", 2)
                      ge("height", 150)
                  }
                  and {
                      eq("gender", 1)
                      le("height", 180)
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  }
```

You can look at a [github](https://github.com/biniama/ParentChildGrailsCriteriaExample) project I did inorder to illustrate this answer.

Comment: this query is not riht answer, since by using this query we will get parents with one boy or one girl which is not our requirment.

Comment: @AnIshA Checkout the new answer and the github project and mark this answer as correct.